# Taking derivative of $\frac{\log x}{\sqrt{x}}$

Tags: derivatives, logarithms

Is it correct to write
$$
\frac{d}{dx}\frac{\log x}{\sqrt{x}} = \frac{2 - \log x}{2x^{{3/2}}}?
$$ I tried applying the quotient rule,
$$
\left(\frac{u}{v}\right)'=\frac{u'v-uv'}{v^2}
$$
but I'm confused on how to get the numerator equal to $2 - \log x$ and the denominator equal to $2x^{3/2}$.

Comment: When you tried to apply the quotient rule, what _did_ you get?

Comment: Show us your work in applying the quotient rule.

Comment: I was able to get $n^{3/2}$ but could not understand where the $\frac{2 - logn}{2}$ comes from

Comment: That doesn't answer the question, random. Show us exactly what you did, we'll show you exactly where it all went wrong.

Comment: random, Show us your workings - *in an edit to your post,* please.  Write your result of $$\frac d{dn}\left(\frac {\log n}{\sqrt n}\right)$$

Comment: I would but it's taking me a long time because I'm not proficient with latex

Comment: Alternately use the product rule $u'v+uv'$ with $u=\ln(x)$ and $v=x^{-1/2}$, I found it often simpler for not having to deal with fractions over fractions. Can you tell what are $u'$ and $v'$ ? The rest just follows.

Comment: @zwim As the quotient rule is derived from a combination of the product rule and the chain rule, this type of band-aid solution in order to _not have to work with fractions within fractions_ is rather retroactive from an educator's standpoint.  I do not think that OP's issue is with the calculus part of this question, but from the _pre-calc_ required -- that is, simplifying rational expressions.

Comment: @Andrew Chin don’t know

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\frac{d}{dx}\frac{\ln x}{\sqrt{x}}= \frac{\frac 1x×\sqrt{x}-\ln x\frac{1}{2\sqrt{}x}}{x} =\frac{2-\ln x}{2x^{3/2}}$